# How to reproduce a chunk load error in React Native app locally

Tags: reactjs, deployment, code-splitting, webpack-splitchunks

I'm trying to figure out a solution to the ChunkLoadError that occurs when a user has a tab open for a long period of time, switches routes, and gets an error because the newly deployed version of the app no longer serves those old JS chunk files. How can I recreate this error locally? I'm trying to build an error boundary and some type of action based on whether the error is received and whether the user switches routes.